# Purpose of Object class in Android Application

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android development. I stumbled upon the Object class. I read the docuementation and it doesn't say much about the purpose of the class. I think it comes in handy when an application has multiple threads. Is there other spots it can be beneficial?Can anyone give me some idea when to use it and the benefits of using it?

Comment: Seems to me that you are struggling with Java itself. Java is object-oriented and uses Objects. A few handle links about OOD: [Tutorial1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) & [Tutorial2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html).
 Like Kumar said.. For handling Threads in Android correctly, an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is used.

Comment: If you're familiar with Java then you know the `Object` class is the *super class* of all the classes including the classes of your own. It is contained by the `java.lang` package which is implicitly imported to your application.

Comment: I had a little knowledge in java. But I jumped in android development directly. And, im kinda strugging but its not that bad though ..

Answer (score 3):

Object class comes from `java.lang.Object`.
Object is the **Super-Class of all the Objects in Java.**

The most common method of Object class, that we keep using is **equals()**

eg:

```
 String s1 = "Hello";
    String s2 = "Hello";

  if (s1.equals(s2){

   }
```

Above example is a simple one.. we use `wait() , notify()` **during the use of threads, and it does work well in Android, though we have Async task to give us painless threading..**
`finalise()` is the method called by GC to garbage collect the object which has no refernce to it..